Flutter NFC Communication throws length error on authentication command
I am rather new to NFC communications, but I need a Flutter app that uses DESFIRE EV1 cards. Now, I am attempting to send the native authentication command, but the response is an error 67, which I believe is a length error. I would appreciate any insight as to why this is happening.
void _startScanning() async {
    try {
      NFCTag tag = await FlutterNfcKit.poll();
      print("Tag: ${tag.id}");
      setState(() {
        _connectedTag = tag;
      });

      if (_connectedTag != null) {
        print("Tag detected");
        switch (_connectedTag!.type) {
          case NFCTagType.mifare_desfire:
            print("DESFire Tag");
            if (_connectedTag != null) {
              try {
                //authenticate to master
                Uint8List command = Uint8List.fromList([0x0A, 0x00]);

                // Convert response to string (or handle accordingly)

                print("Command Data: $command");

                // Transceive the command
                var response = await FlutterNfcKit.transceive(command);

                String responseData = response.map((e) => e.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')).join(' ');

                print("Response Data: $response");

                try {
                  //fail on purpose
                  var result2 = await FlutterNfcKit.transceive(response);
                  print("Response Data: $result2");

                } catch (e) {
                  print("Error: $e");
                }
              } catch (e) {
                print("Error: $e");
              }
            }
            FlutterNfcKit.finish(iosAlertMessage: "");
            break;
          case NFCTagType.mifare_ultralight:
            print("MIFARE Ultralight Tag");
            break;
          case NFCTagType.mifare_classic:
            print("MIFARE Classic Tag");
            break;
          case NFCTagType.iso7816:
            print("ISO 7816 Tag");
            _sendMifareCommand([0x1A, 0x00]);
            break;
          case NFCTagType.iso15693:
            print("ISO 15693 Tag");
            break;
          default:
            print("Unknown Tag");
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
    }
  }


You are trying to run native commands, but e.g. on Android you need to use wrapped commands in general. The wrapped command is some bytes longer, for that reason you received the length error.
